# Powershell parameter if else

Tags: powershell-3.0

```
function global:Get-Shares(){
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
    Get Shares
    .DESCRIPTION
    This function fetches all shares on the computer when you run get-shares localhost.  If you
    just run get-shares then it will show all the non-$ shares.
    .LINK
    You can use "et" to end the transcript.
    .PARAMETER prefix
    The prefix for the transcript file name. Default: PowerShell_get-shares
    .EXAMPLE
    }
    #>
    param (
        [string]$Computername, [string]$Allshares
    )
    [AllowNull()]
    $computername = 'localhost'
    $Allshares = gwmi -Computer $computername -Class Win32_Share | Where-Object { $_.Name -notlike "*$" }
    if ($ComputerName -eq 'localhost') {
    gwmi -Computer $ComputerName -Class Win32_Share 

    }   
    else {
    gwmi -Computer $computername -Class Win32_Share | Where-Object { $_.Name -notlike "*$" }
}
}
```

Why does my else statement not work? I only get the result for the if ######  statement where I run get-shares or get-shares localhost

Answer (score 0):

You definitely has to look in to Get-Help [About_Function_Advanced](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/about/about_Functions_Advanced)

here, you can mention default value for $ComputerName in Param() block itself.
and allow null attribute has to be n=mentioned in Param block, not outside

```
Param(
[AllowNull()]
$ComputerName = 'localhost'
)
```

and if  `$ComputerName` id localhost, No need to use `gwmi -computername $ComputerName`, just `gwmi -Class Win32_Share` is enough.

And the main problem here is, even if you mention value for `$ComputerName`, it will get replaced by `$ComputerNme = 'localhost'` and only if will be passed.

Regards,

kvprasoon